# Current page class in rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-lists, current-page

I have simple navigation bar in my rails app(`Home`, `News`, `Contact`, etc). And I need to define current page to add `:class => 'active'`. I find few solution to define current page. And I even created own version. But all of them are reduced to one:

`<li class=<%= current_page?(tratata) ? "active" : nil %>...</li>`

How I can to apply this solution to all `<li> - elements` but not to write this every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to do it, but will give you some thoughts on pulling the current controller and action.

You can look at https://github.com/weppos/tabs_on_rails for more ideas on how to make it cleaner code. But this requires a bit more setup. You would create a tabs_tag function that would check the current page and do different styling. Personally, I didn't care for this gem too much and prefer to style my pages my own way.

```
<%= tabs_tag do |tab| %>
  <%= tab.home      'Homepage', root_path %>
  <%= tab.dashboard 'Dashboard', dashboard_path %>
  <%= tab.account   'Account', account_path %>
<% end %>

if "#{controller.controller_name.to_s}.#{controller.action_name.to_s}" == "pages.index"
  <li class='active'>
else
  <li>
end
```

or use a helper method

```
def current_page(page,action)
  if controller.controller_name.to_s == page && controller.action_name.to_s == action
    'active'
  else
    'not_active'
 end
end
```

and in your view

```
<li class="<%= current_page('pages','index') %>">
```

Comment: wait. If I use that I will have all `<li>` elements with `class => 'not_active'`

Comment: that was just an example, you could have left the `else` part out.

Comment: I understood. This is shorter solution than `current_page?()` and I like that. Thanks! But I have to write every time `<li class=...>` at each element.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to check if the page the user is on matches the name of the controller they're visiting (you could also do a controller name / action name combination for extra specificity).

**application_helper**

```
def nav_helper(arg)
  controller_name == arg ? "current" : ""
end
```

**view**

```
<li class="<%= nav_helper('about') %>">
  <a href="#">A link</a>
</li>
```

#### EDIT:

Woops, I wrote this before you edited your question.  To add this to all 'li' tags, use another helper which uses [`content_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) and place the `nav_helper` method inside of it.

Comment: I Understood and `content_tag` would be nice but my navbar is not generate dinamically. I need to use this helper for each `<li>` elements?